# Accessing the Activity using a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to access the activity using my fragment.

This is how I am accessing it:

```
    RelativeLayout titleBar = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pullupTitleBar);
    titleBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

the activities view does not change invisible though. Also tried View.GONE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to actually do it the other way round and access the fragment from the activity instead!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
  getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.pullupTitleBar);
```